# How to display two horizontal unordered lists on one line?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to recreate the Google homepage as an HTML exercise, and am having trouble with the footer, which displays two sets of links on the same line, each with different alignments: one aligned left, the other right. However, I haven't yet succeeded in doing the following two tasks at once:

1. Create two lists, one aligned left and one right
2. Display both lists on the same line

Here's the text of my html file so far, with the relevant code in the footer tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm"> Gmail</a></li>
        <li><a>Images</a></li>
        <li><a><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGYAAABmCAMAAAAOARRQAAAANlBMVEX///8AAADg4OAkJCQoKCiFhYWCgoLk5OT7+/vu7u4dHR0YGBggICBERERBQUFHR0eTk5PAwMD3J6laAAAAvUlEQVRoge2YyQ7DIAwFE9YspCX//7PtgVaARHyjFZm5Pj3NybbkaQIAAPgBi1clfknJWgVqFStt/CPonHD4lMS9CPQexUobFeYSrVLiqmB2YuVCo6uOaWqsWEGDBg2am2j6bGh/aJOjn997sxWB2aJYadPpegIMxRpdSfyMx1kF7hQrbdRebY5NXjbNyoVmrA2NBg0aNCNp+hyC942yOflZs2VyihWAm8ATkickGjRo0HTR8ITkCQkAAH/BCztRGS1ttQr7AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" class="appimg"></a></li>
        <li><button class="bluebtn">Sign In</button></li>
    </ul>
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "page-wrap">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <img src = "https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--pEKSmwzm--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/1414228815325188681.jpg" class="logo"/>
        <input type="text"/><br>

        <div>
            <button>Google Search</button>
            <button>I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
        </div>


    </div>
    <footer class="site-footer">
        <div class="bottomlist">
            <ul class = "left">
                <li class="left"><a>Advertising</a></li>
                <li class="left"><a>Business</a></li>
                <li class="left"><a>About</a></li>

            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li class="right"><a>Privacy</a></li>
                <li class="right"><a>Terms</a></li>
                <li class="right"><a>Settings</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>   
</body>


</html>
```

And here's the relevant css:

```
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    text-align: right;
}

ul.left{
    text-align: left;
}

ul.right{
    text-align: right;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}

li.right {
    text-align: right;
}

a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}

a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

img.logo{
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
}

img.appimg{
    display: inline;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}

input {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 25px;
}

div {
    text-align: center;
}

div.bottom{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: 
}

div.bottomlist{
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

button {
    margin: 0 auto;
    font: 13.3333px Arial;
 }

button.bluebtn{
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    border: 5px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 75px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -142px; 
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  height: 142px; 
}
.site-footer {
  background: gray;
}
```

Comment: In questions like that you should make an online demo on services such as [tag:jsbin], [tag:jsfiddle], etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will probably want to [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/float) your lists e.g

```
<ul class="left">
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
</ul>
<ul class="right">
<li>Three</li>
<li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

and the CSS:

```
li {display:inline-block}
.left {float:left}
.right {float:right}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ox03mtte/

Comment: That was exactly it! I just had to change my text-align fields to float fields and the alignment was fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this is to put each of your Unordered lists into two seperate div containers.

eg/

```
<div style="float:left; width:50%;">
      <ul style="Display:in-line-block;">
       <li>1</li>
       <li>2</li>
      </ul>
</div>
<div style="float:right; width:50%;">
       <ul style="Display:in-line-block;">
       <li>1</li>
       <li>2</li>
       </ul>
 </div>
```

If the container is being pushed to the line below, it could be due to margins. In this case you will want to reduce the width to a lower percentage or remove the margins.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with placing the lists in divs of their own (Inside your 'bottomlist'), and removing the classes from the `<ul>`  and `<li>` tags. Like this:

```
<div class="bottomlist">
         <div class="left">
        <ul>
             <li><a>Advertising</a></li>
             <li><a>Business</a></li>
             <li><a>About</a></li>

                        </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
        <ul>
             <li><a>Privacy</a></li>
             <li><a>Terms</a></li>
             <li><a>Settings</a></li>
                        </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

The CSS would be something like this:

```
#bottomleft .left { 
display: block;
position: relative;
float:left;
width: 50%;
    }

#bottomleft .right { 
display: block;
position: relative;
float:right;
width: 50%;
    }
```

Add margins / padding for spacing between the lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#logo">Item one</a></li>
<li><a href="#logo">Item two</a></li>
</ul>


#menu{
padding:2;
margin:2; 
color:#fff; 
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; 
white-space:nowrap; 
list-style-type:none; 
} 
#menu li {
display:inline;
}
#menu li a {
padding:0.2em 1em;
background:#fc6;
color:#000;
text-decoration:none; 
float:left;
border:1px solid #000; 
}
#menu li a:hover{
background:#08c;
color:#fff;
}
```